# How to notate a 16:15 frequency in just intonation?

Tags: notation, just-intonation

I've often came across tables just chromatic scales like so:

`C: 1:1`
`C#: 16:15`
`D: 9:8`

And so forth. I know that at least in Ben Johnston notation, the sharp sign implies that a note's frequency is being multiplied by 25:24, and that is clearly not what I'm looking for here. I'm trying to write a note that is somewhat analogous to C# in equal temperament.

Any help would be much appreciated.

Comment: https://www.kylegann.com/BJNotation.html Here's a resource that probably helps.

Answer (score 3):

The note you are looking for is Dflat-minus.

D is 9:8. Dflat is D times 24:25 = 216:200 = 27:25. Dflat-minus is Dflat times 80:81 = 2160:2025 = 16:15

Answer (score 0):

A "just" seventh is 15/8 so your 16/15 is equivalent octave-equivalent to the just semitone between B and C. Or using E to F, the solution of E*X=F with both moved to C gives 5/4*X=4/3 which has 15/16 as a solution. I didn't see any special notation in various articles on the subject.